# Тест не завершается с tearDown

Tags: php, yii2, юнит-тесты, codeception

Простой unit-Test модели в Yii2 проверяющий поля, обязательные для заполнения, и уникальность поля `name`. При запуске с `tearDown()` тест не завершается, выходит без ошибок.

> D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\yii2apps\consult\tests>codecept run
>   codeception\unit\models\GroupTest.php Codeception PHP Testing
>   Framework v2.1.5 Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and
>   contributors.
>
> Unit Tests (2)
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Trying to test empty attributes
>   (codeception\unit\models\GroupTest::testEmptyAttributes)...
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\yii2apps\consult\tests>

Если вместо `tearDown` использовать `setUp()`, то тест успешно завершает работу

> D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\yii2apps\consult\tests>codecept run
>   codeception\unit\models\GroupTest.php Codeception PHP Testing
>   Framework v2.1.5 Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and
>   contributors.
>
> Unit Tests (2)
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test empty attributes
>   (codeception\unit\models\GroupTest::testEmptyAttributes) Test unique
>
> ### name (codeception\unit\models\GroupTest::testUniqueName)
>
> Time: 832 ms, Memory: 11.00Mb
>
> OK (2 tests, 6 assertions)
>
> D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\yii2apps\consult\tests>

Сам тест:

```
<?php
namespace codeception\unit\models;

use app\models\Group;
use yii\codeception\TestCase;

class GroupTest extends TestCase
{

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Group::deleteAll();
    }

    public function testEmptyAttributes(){
        $model = new Group();

        $this->assertFalse($model->validate(),'validation failed');
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('name',$model->getErrors(),'check existed name');
    }

    public function testUniqueName(){
        $model = new Group(['name'=>'testGroup']);
        $newModel = new Group(['name'=>'testGroup']);

        $this->assertTrue($model->validate(),'model validated');
        $this->assertTrue($model->save(),'model saved');

        $this->assertFalse($newModel->validate(),'model validation failed');
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('name',$newModel->getErrors(),'check unique name');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый кит, на котором стоит модульное тестирование - это запрет использования внешних зависимостей, как внутри кода, так и снаружи, в вашем случае это база данных. **Вам вообще не нужно тестировать модель**, в данном случае вы банально тестируете фреймворк и сохранение данных в БД, а не свой код. Тестировать валидацию саму по себе бессмысленно, потому что тестируя случай "не забыл ли я верно указать поле" вы ровно так же можете забыть указать проверку на конкретное поле в самом тесте, и получить тест, который не только успешно выполняется, но и успешно пропускает дефект.
Ну и, кроме всего прочего, **модульные тесты должны выполняться одной командой на свежей машине, на которой нет ничего, кроме интерпретатора языка**. Любой разработчик должен быть способен чекаутнуть репозиторий, выкачать зависимости и запустить проект.

Что касательно этого случая, то, очевидно, `Group::deleteAll` прибивает сам PHP - в нем так или иначе выпадает фатальная ошибка, вызывается exit, генерируется segfault - но сама работа PHP в этот момент прерывается. Ищите проблему в нем, залезайте в процесс с дебаггером, смотрите, на какой строчке валится.

Ну и последнее, сообщение, которое вы вводите в проверках - это сообщение, которое должно быть выведено при возникновении ошибки (у вас же, наоборот, сообщение говорит о том, что всё окей).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. PHP вылетает с ошибкой "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getDb() on null". Не понимаю что может ему мешать получить конфиг подключения к БД в tearDown(), но успешно его использовать в setUp().
Киты модульного тестирования? Если не сложно, дайте линк на эту инфу и best practics в тестировании. Все что я находил до этого момента было на уровне $this->assertTrue(true)